# Why are the lines around my multicolumn cell misaligned?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, rules, multicolumn

In the following table, why does the double line before the `diff` column not go through? I guess all the `multicolumn{1}` are wrong? How can I fix it?

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|c|c|c||r|}\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c||}{} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Model 1} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Model 2}  &
\multicolumn{1}{||r|}{}\\

\multicolumn{1}{|c||}{Task} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(a)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(b)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{(c)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(a)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(b)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(c)} &
\multicolumn{1}{||r|}{diff}\\\hline

Foo     & 1 & 2 & 3 & A & B & C & + \\
Bar     & 1 & 2 & 3 & A & B & C & + \\\hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{whatever}\label{tab:whatever}
\end{table}
```

[image: fugly table]

Answer (score 7):

A `\multicolumn` overwrites the **right** line setting of its cell(s) defined by the tabular header, except of the **first** cell, there it overwrites the right **and** left line setting.

```
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|c|c|c|c||r|}\hline

\multicolumn{1}{|c||}{} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Model 1} &
\multicolumn{3}{c||}{Model 2}  &
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{}\\

\multicolumn{1}{|c||}{Task} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(a)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(b)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{(c)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(a)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(b)} &
\multicolumn{1}{c||}{(c)} &
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{diff}\\\hline

Foo     & 1 & 2 & 3 & A & B & C & + \\
Bar     & 1 & 2 & 3 & A & B & C & + \\\hline

\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer to your question (others did that). However, I think you can make a better looking table by following the advice in the booktabs package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 1}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2}&\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
Tack & (a) & (b) & (c) & (a) & (b) & (c) & diff\\
\midrule
Foo & 1 & 2 & 3 & A & B & C & $+$\\
Bar & 1 & 2 & 3 & A & B & C & $+$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{@{}lccccccc@{}}`

Comment: @Herbert: Only if you don't want the rules to extend. I'd only use that if I needed the extra space. I think it looks better with the longer rules.

Comment: @TH: it was you who wrote: "following the advice in the booktabs" ...

Comment: @Herbert: Yep. You got me there. =)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is to change some of your code as the following lines.

```
\multicolumn{1}{|c||}{} &
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Model 1} &
\multicolumn{3}{c||}{Model 2}  &
\\
```

and

```
\multicolumn{1}{c||}{(c)} &
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{diff}\\\hline
```