# How to align \vrule partial vertical lines in a pgfplotstable

Tags: tables, formatting, pgfplotstable

I had a look at this post on [Misaligned multicolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8701/why-are-the-lines-around-my-multicolumn-cell-misaligned) but it doesn't really solve my problem. I have the code below which is supposed to produce a table with a blue line for the first row and red lines for the other two.

In the table below there should be a single blue line and a single contiguous red line below it, with the numbers all aligned.

Could someone guide me to what I'm doing wrong? I recognize the dire imprecations against vertical lines but in the final output this will present financial information and I thought it would be useful to clearly separate the inflows from the outflows with a colour coded side line.

If anyone can help with the `Misplaced \omit` error too that would be really helpful

[image: Vertical lines supposed to be aligned]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\def\pgfplotstableeach(#1-#2,#3-#4,#5){% columns 1-2 rows 3-4 input 5
  \xdef\ACCUM{}%
  \foreach \col in {#1,...,#2} {%
    \foreach \ro in {#3,...,#4} {%
    \toks0=\expandafter{\ACCUM}%
    \edef\temp{every row \ro\space column \col/.style}%
    \toks1={#5}%
    \xdef\ACCUM{\the\toks0 \temp={\the\toks1},}%
    }%
  }%
  \message{setting \meaning\ACCUM^^J}%
  \expandafter\pgfplotstableset\expandafter{\ACCUM}%
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&,header=false]{%
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\%
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\%
9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\%
}\mytable

\pgfplotstableset{
  outline/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox{##1}}},
  vblue/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{blue}\vrule width 2pt height 1ex}l}{##1}}},
  vred/.style= {postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\multicolumn{1}{!{\color{red} \vrule width 2pt height 2ex}l}{##1}}}
}

\pgfplotstableeach(0-0,1-2,{vred})
\pgfplotstableeach(0-0,0-0,{vblue})

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
debug,
column name={},
every row 2 column 1/.style={outline},
every row 1 column 0/.style={vred},
every row no 0/.style={after row={\rule{0pt}{2em}}}
]\mytable


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content is inserted into the cell too late for `\multicolumn` which must have no non-expandable tokens before it. So something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\def\pgfplotstableeach(#1-#2,#3-#4,#5){% columns 1-2 rows 3-4 input 5
  \xdef\ACCUM{}%
  \foreach \col in {#1,...,#2} {%
    \foreach \ro in {#3,...,#4} {%
    \toks0=\expandafter{\ACCUM}%
    \edef\temp{every row \ro\space column \col/.style}%
    \toks1={#5}%
    \xdef\ACCUM{\the\toks0 \temp={\the\toks1},}%
    }%
  }%
  \message{setting \meaning\ACCUM^^J}%
  \expandafter\pgfplotstableset\expandafter{\ACCUM}%
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&,header=false]{%
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\%
5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\%
9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\%
}\mytable

\pgfplotstableset{
  outline/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content=\fbox{##1}}},
  vblue/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={\color{blue}\vrule width 2pt height 1ex\relax}\,##1}},
  vred/.style= {postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={\color{red} \vrule width 2pt height 2ex\relax}\,##1}}
}

\pgfplotstableeach(0-0,1-2,{vred})
\pgfplotstableeach(0-0,0-0,{vblue})

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
debug,
column name={},
every row 2 column 1/.style={outline},
every row 1 column 0/.style={vred},
every row no 0/.style={after row={\rule{0pt}{2em}}}
]\mytable


\end{document}
```

If you want the lines to run together like this:

[image]

Just delete the height component of the rules:

```
  vblue/.style={postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={\color{blue}\vrule width 2pt\relax}\,##1}},
  vred/.style= {postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={\color{red} \vrule width 2pt\relax}\,##1}}
```

Comment: That's brilliant @DavidCarlisle thank you. For my education could you explain what the new code is doing? I don't quite understand why it works, especially the last backslash. Thanks.

Comment: the \, is just a thin space to separate the rule you could replace it by `\hspace{1cm}` the `{\color...}` group before that is a coloured rule and `##1` is (apparently) the original cell contents which must go through two levels of macro definition internally hence requiring a doubled `#`. The main point is that it is too late to change the cell preamble with multicolumn so you need to put the vrule _in_ the cell content and space it "by hand" to separate it from the digits in the cell.