# How to align a vertical line at the end of the multicolumn in a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

How to align this vertical line at the end of the multi-column?

I searched, but I could not find an answer for such problem. This was originated from [How to fix this Package array Error: Only one column-spec allowed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367069/how-to-fix-this-package-array-error-only-one-column-spec-allowed)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,tabularx,multirow}

\begin{document}

\section{Custos}

    \begin{tabular}
    {|
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{3.9cm}|} % Item
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{1.9cm}|} % Quantidade
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{3.0cm}|} % Valor
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{2.6cm}|} % Valor
    }

        \hline Item &   Quantidade  &   Valor Unitário (R\$) & Valor Total (R\$) \\ \hline
        Total       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                  & 165,00            \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

## Update 1

I find another question which seems to have the same problem, but it is not easy to understand what they did to fix it. I have to open my diff program to compare the original code and the fixed code:

1. [Why are the lines around my multicolumn cell misaligned?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8701/why-are-the-lines-around-my-multicolumn-cell-misaligned)

[image]

On the right there is the fixed code, on the left is the original code.

That table goes from this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

---

## Update 2

By [@David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090) comment, I find out that the question mentionated on the `Update 1` is different from this one:

> the edited question is an entirely different issue, please don't change the question that way invalidating all posted answers. The added question is the common issue of putting | on the wrong side of the cell boundary, the original question is unrelkated to that and just about your mis-use of

Comment: why are you replacing the default tabcolsep of 4pt by a space of 3pt, just on one side of each vertical rule?

Comment: Nothing special, just to keep the code explicit, rather than implicit. So I can configure the table more easily. I would do this just for now while I am not experienced with latex tables.

Comment: But why do you explicitly want 4pt on one side of each  rule and 3pt on the other???

Comment: Also `\hsize=1.1\hsize` is just wrong.

Comment: I copied it from my other table, which I had to remove a little the adjust to stop a overfull warning. About `\hsize` I do not know what is it doing exactly. This is the original table: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366155/how-to-write-a-table-a-little-larger-than-the-paragraphs-with-centered-columns, on the answer there, the guy put `\hsize` on it, but looks like he did not say why.

Comment: that is a tabularx X column, so entirely different thing.

Comment: If you have a vertical rule in the centre of your inter-column space it is to say the least odd to just shrink the space on one side of the rule making it off-centre

Comment: the edited question is an entirely different issue, please don't change the question that way invalidating all posted answers. The added question is the common issue of putting `|` on the wrong side of the cell boundary, the original question  is unrelated to that and just about your mis-use of `@`

Comment: Sorry, but I did not know that question was unrelated. They seem to be the same problem. I updated the question explaining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your preamble has obscured the necessary column spec:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,tabularx,multirow}

\begin{document}

\section{Custos}

    \begin{tabular}
    {|
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{3.9cm}|} % Item
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{1.9cm}|} % Quantidade
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{3.0cm}|} % Valor
        *1{@{\hspace{3.0pt}}>{ \RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.1\hsize }p{2.6cm}|} % Valor
    }

        \hline Item &   Quantidade  &   Valor Unitário (R\$) & Valor Total (R\$) \\ \hline
        Total       & \multicolumn{2}{c|@{\hspace{3.0pt}}}{}                  & 165,00            \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I left in the `\hsize=1.1\hsize` but it is completely wrong! Also as commented under the question, the `@` usage here is making the vertical rules no longer centred in the inter-column space.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem was the spacing adjusting I was doing on each column from the main table. Therefore I also needed to adjust the column on the inner column table. To fix it was need to change `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}` to `\multicolumn{2}{c|@{\hspace{3.0pt}}}{}`.

Comment: @user that lines up the `|` as I show in my answer but it is still very wrong, the `|` should be centred in the space between the columns  and you are making it off centre using `@` in this way.

Answer (score 2):

You are over-complicating things here. If you need to adjust the `tabcolsep`, just overwrite the default `4pt` by `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,tabularx,multirow}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{document}

\section{Custos}

\begin{tabular}
    {| R{3.9cm}| % Item
       R{1.9cm}| % Quantidade
       R{3.0cm}| % Valor
       R{2.6cm}| % Valor
    }
    \hline 
    Item    & Quantidade    &   Valor Unitário (R\$) & Valor Total (R\$) \\ \hline
    Total   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}                  & 165,00            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\RaggedRight` do not need the `\arraybackslash`

Comment: @Herbert: True, thanks, I tend to use it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I add to `geometry` option `showframe` for showing page layout. Now is better visible table size and how unnecessary complicated is your column style definitions.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,
            a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,tabularx,multirow}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{document}

\section{Custos}

\begin{tabular}
    {| R{4cm}| % Item
       R{2cm}| % Quantidade
       R{3.5cm}| % Valor
       R{3cm}| % Valor
    }
    \hline
    Item    & Quantidade    &   Valor Unitário (R\$) & Valor Total (R\$) \\ \hline
    Total   & \multicolumn{2}{R{4.9cm}|}{}                  & 165,00            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** 
Maybe you will like the following solution:

[image]

where for table is used `tabularx` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,
            a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,tabularx,multirow}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight}X|}

\begin{document}

\section{Custos}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
    {| >{\hsize=1.75\hsize}R   % Item
                           R   % Quantidade
       >{\hsize=1.25\hsize}R   % Valor
                           R   % Valor
    }
    \hline
Item    &   Quantidade            &   Valor Unitário (R\$)  & Valor Total (R\$) \\ \hline
Total   &   \multicolumn{2}{R}{}                            &   165,00            \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution for the first question:

The culprit is the `@{\hspace{3pt}}`, which you didn't used in `\multicolumn`. But it's better to set  `\tabcolsep` to `3pt` for the entire table:

```
\documentclass[12pt, brazil]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,tabularx,multirow}

\begin{document}

\section{Custos}

{\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}
    {|>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.9cm}|% Item
    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{1.9cm}| % Quantidade
    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.0cm}| % Valor
    >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{2.6cm}|} % Valor
        \hline %
        Item & Quantidade & Valor Unitário (R\$) & Valor Total (R\$) \\ %
        \hline
        Total & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Lalala} & 165,00 \\ %
        \hline
    \end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]